# Conditional Expression in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I wrote this expression and getting errors, not sure why.

I am trying to get if `Fields!Started.Value` is in between 3-6 days old, and `Fields!NumSuccess.Value = 4`, then I should get "Yellow".

If `Fields!Started.Value` is more than 7 days older than today, and `Fields!NumSuccess.Value` not equal to 4, then I should get "Red".

And finally, if none of those works, then I should have "DarkGreen"

But this code is giving me error message..can you help please?

```
=IIF((DateDiff("d",Today(),Fields!Started.Value)>=3 and (Fields!Started.Value) <= 6), AND (=Fields!NumSuccess.Value)=4 "Yellow",
            IIF(DateDiff("d",Today(),Fields!Started.Value)>= 7, AND (=Fields!NumSuccess.Value)!=4, "Red",
                true,"DarkGreen"))
```

Comment: You have extra = signs before Fields!NumSuccess.
What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Switch` function which is cleaner and readable:

```
=Switch(
  DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,CDate(Fields!Started.Value),Today())<=6 and
  DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,CDate(Fields!Started.Value),Today())>=3 and
  Fields!NumSuccess.Value=4, "Yellow",
  DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,CDate(Fields!Started.Value),Today())>7 and
  Fields!NumSuccess.Value<>4, "Red",
  true,"DarkGreen"
)
```

Comment: I came up with the same expression about 3 minutes after you. For anyone interested, the () after Today is not needed. Sometimes the IDE will show the red squiggly line under them. This will work with, or without them.

Comment: @R.Richards, ohh I mispelled good eye of yours. about today and today() you're right being first one the cleanest.

Comment: Thank you every one. @alejandrozuleta Thank you once again for your help, with just a little tweak with your code, I got what I was looking for.

Comment: =Switch(
  DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,CDate(Fields!Started.Value),Today())<=6 and
  DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,CDate(Fields!Started.Value),Today())>=3 and
  Fields!NumSuccess.Value=4, "Orange",
  DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,CDate(Fields!Started.Value),Today())>7 OR 
  Fields!NumSuccess.Value <>4, "Red",
  true,"DarkGreen"
)